# Find all groups that meets the condition

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, clustering, hash-function, data-mining

I have $n$ elements, each of them have two unsigned int attributes $x$ and $y$.

Now I'd like to find out all the groups that fit the following condition:

$A.x \geq B.y$ and $B.x \geq A.y$.

The groups can be a number of $2$,$3, \ldots n$. For example, $A,B,C$ can meet this requirement with each other, so this forms a group of $3$.

How to find them efficiently?

Comment: Does A.x refer to the first attribute of a single element in the first cluster or every first attribute in the first cluster?  Can two clusters share elements?

Comment: Or are $A$ and $B$ two elements of the same cluster, and can only be in the same cluster if they have the specified relation?

Comment: They can share elements.  I have $n$ elements, $A,B,C,...$. $x$ and $y$ are their two attributes. Clusters are built later.

Comment: This is NOT the traditional meaning of clustering, just find all the groups that meet this requirement.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me.  Is the relation you put in line 3 a requirement of elements in a cluster?

Comment: Yes. In each of the group, any two of them meet this requirement.

Comment: This is equivalent then to finding complete directed subgraphs.  Let every element be a vertex (node) if $A.x\geq B.y$ then put an arc from $A$ to $B$ if $B.x\geq A.y$ then put an arc from $B$ to $A$.  You want to find subgraphs where every pair of vertices $u, v$ has arcs $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$.  You need to find all complete directed subgraphs.